# How do I convert base64 to an html file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, base64

I am getting a mail body encoded in base64:

PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-PGhlYWQ-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-WW91IGNhbiBzaW1wbHkgV0lQRSBPdXQgeW91ciBlbWFpbCBmcm9tIE1haWxpbmcgTGlzdMKgPGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL25saWMuc3BlZWRvbWFpbGh1Yi5pbi9saXN0cy9sYzczMTdoYWhnM2Q4L3Vuc3Vic2NyaWJlL2F3MzUxYXhidHY3ZjYvZGozOTR5a2hwMzkyYy8zIiB0YXJnZXQ9Il9ibGFuayI-IGNsaWNrIGhlcmUgPC9hPjwvZGl2Pgo8aW1nIHdpZHRoPSIxIiBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9ubGljLnNwZWVkb21haWxodWIuaW4vY2FtcGFpZ25zL2RqMzk0eWtocDM5MmMvdHJhY2stb3BlbmluZy9hdzM1MWF4YnR2N2Y2IiBhbHQ9IiIvPjwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw-DQoNCg==

I have an html page:

```html
<a href="data:text/css;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-PGhlYWQ-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-WW91IGNhbiBzaW1wbHkgV0lQRSBPdXQgeW91ciBlbWFpbCBmcm9tIE1haWxpbmcgTGlzdMKgPGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL25saWMuc3BlZWRvbWFpbGh1Yi5pbi9saXN0cy9sYzczMTdoYWhnM2Q4L3Vuc3Vic2NyaWJlL2F3MzUxYXhidHY3ZjYvZGozOTR5a2hwMzkyYy8zIiB0YXJnZXQ9Il9ibGFuayI-IGNsaWNrIGhlcmUgPC9hPjwvZGl2Pgo8aW1nIHdpZHRoPSIxIiBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9ubGljLnNwZWVkb21haWxodWIuaW4vY2FtcGFpZ25zL2RqMzk0eWtocDM5MmMvdHJhY2stb3BlbmluZy9hdzM1MWF4YnR2N2Y2IiBhbHQ9IiIvPjwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw-DQoNCg==" />See html</a>
```

which on clicking See html opens a file with html written in the form of text:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div align="center">
      <a href="http://nlic.speedomailhub.in/campaigns/dj394ykhp392c/track-url/aw351axbtv7f6/9c18729445dcca36e45efc0daa4c94be18b198aa">
      <img alt="" src="http://hasq.speedomailhub.in/sk55119gb8900/dj394ykhp392c/vq015xz7ba1c2_1.png"></a>
    </div>
    
    <div style="text-align:center;">You can simply WIPE Out your email from Mailing ListÂ <a href="http://nlic.speedomailhub.in/lists/lc7317hahg3d8/unsubscribe/aw351axbtv7f6/dj394ykhp392c/3" target="_blank"> click here </a>
    </div>
    
    <img width="1" src="http://nlic.speedomailhub.in/campaigns/dj394ykhp392c/track-opening/aw351axbtv7f6" alt=""/>
  </body>
  
  </html>
```

How do I show this as an actual html file, just like it shows on run code instead of just plain html text.

Is there any way I can directly convert the base64 to an actual html page. IS it possible with python?

Comment: (Unrelated to your actual question) The data url in the `a` element's  `href` attribute starts with `data:text/css` which denotes a css ruleset and not html. Better use `data:text/html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it with `iframe`. Simply make sure you use the correct data (`data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64`) and that you have a valid converted HTML

```css
iframe {
 border:none;
 width:100%;
 height:1000px;
}


body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+DQo8aHRtbD4NCjxoZWFkPjxtZXRhIG5hbWU9ImNoYXJzZXQiIGNvbnRlbnQ9InV0Zi04Ij4NCiAgPHRpdGxlPjwvdGl0bGU+DQogIDwvaGVhZD4NCiAgPGJvZHk+DQogICAgPGRpdiBhbGlnbj0iY2VudGVyIj4NCiAgICAgIDxhIGhyZWY9Imh0dHA6Ly9ubGljLnNwZWVkb21haWxodWIuaW4vY2FtcGFpZ25zL2RqMzk0eWtocDM5MmMvdHJhY2stdXJsL2F3MzUxYXhidHY3ZjYvOWMxODcyOTQ0NWRjY2EzNmU0NWVmYzBkYWE0Yzk0YmUxOGIxOThhYSI+DQogICAgICA8aW1nIGFsdD0iIiBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9oYXNxLnNwZWVkb21haWxodWIuaW4vc2s1NTExOWdiODkwMC9kajM5NHlraHAzOTJjL3ZxMDE1eHo3YmExYzJfMS5wbmciPjwvYT4NCiAgICA8L2Rpdj4NCiAgICANCiAgICA8ZGl2IHN0eWxlPSJ0ZXh0LWFsaWduOmNlbnRlcjsiPllvdSBjYW4gc2ltcGx5IFdJUEUgT3V0IHlvdXIgZW1haWwgZnJvbSBNYWlsaW5nIExpc3TDgiA8YSBocmVmPSJodHRwOi8vbmxpYy5zcGVlZG9tYWlsaHViLmluL2xpc3RzL2xjNzMxN2hhaGczZDgvdW5zdWJzY3JpYmUvYXczNTFheGJ0djdmNi9kajM5NHlraHAzOTJjLzMiIHRhcmdldD0iX2JsYW5rIj4gY2xpY2sgaGVyZSA8L2E+DQogICAgPC9kaXY+DQogICAgDQogICAgPGltZyB3aWR0aD0iMSIgc3JjPSJodHRwOi8vbmxpYy5zcGVlZG9tYWlsaHViLmluL2NhbXBhaWducy9kajM5NHlraHAzOTJjL3RyYWNrLW9wZW5pbmcvYXczNTFheGJ0djdmNiIgYWx0PSIiLz4NCiAgPC9ib2R5Pg0KICANCiAgPC9odG1sPg=="></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert a base64 file try by using a third party web like https://www.base64decode.org/ but what the file is supposed to be for? it seem like it's corrupted.. where do you get it/how do you created it?

Answer (score -1):

You can't convert image to html, only you can do it's just parse text from this image, But not all text will be parsed correctly.

you can try this approach [Scan and extract text from an image using Python libraries](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/document-scanner/)

What you ask, this work can done `HTML Coder`

Comment: Why do you think this is some image data? While the decoded text stream seems to be partially corrupted the intelligible fragments clearly show that it originates from html (though the data url is mislabeled wrt the MIME type (text/css instead of text/html)

Comment: @collapsar Because in example i see image, and base64 usually used for image, it's a weird use base64 for source html code

Comment: In the example you see a html page that happens to contain graphics. You are mistaken in believing that base64 is 'usually used for image' - it is used for _any_ kind of binary data that is processed by systems that assume ascii textual data. Historically that has been email (I'd suspect that pdf attachments are the most common use case). Using base64 for html source code (or any other content) is not weird btw; eg. you might want to avoid issues character set issues with the software handling the data.